# Navigating to page containing ion-slides causing the swipe behaviour to stop working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ion-slides

I created two pages with identical sliders. (say HomePage and Page1Page)
I place Navigation links to the other in each (via navCtrl.push)

Now while the slider works well (that is responds to both swipe and clicks on pager) on the HomePage, it does not respond correctly to swipe on the Page1Page. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Plunkr:
http://embed.plnkr.co/8v0nBm/

Going back to the HomePage from the Page1Page causes the slider to stop working there too!

All help/ideas appreciated.

Comment: Dont have enough reputation so posting it as answer. In your plunkr try replacing `push` with `setRoot` in your `home.page.ts`, while navigating from Home Page to page1. It seems to be working. I am still trying to figure out why is it not working in push. Will update here if i get any more details
Hope this at-least provides you a small break-through

Comment: There's an open issue related to this [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10271). Maybe you could try if [this PR](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/pull/11100) fixes it...

Comment: @sebaferreras the PR mentions merged 2 months ago, no?

Comment: oh, you're right, sorry for that :(